# On Click in Form, see if value exists in table. If yes run Query 1 to Update, If no run Query 2 to Append

Tags: ms-access

I am an Access novice, so this may be easier than I'm thinking. I have two queries to run On Click. Both look at existing values in a table. I want to run Query 1 if the Primary Key exists, else run Query 2 to Append.

Below are the table/form/query names:

```
    Table.Field: COMPLY_R_APPROVE_UPDATES.CASENUM
    Form: [Forms]![frmOfficeAuditUpd]![CASENUM]
    Query 1: DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryUpdate_Approve_Updates"
    Query 2: DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryAppend_Approve_Updates"
```

Comment: Read about Dlookup() function

Comment: Do you have the value on your form?